# $_GET not getting the URL data

Tags: php

I'd like to make a small flashMessage without sessions using $_GET global in php, i've seen other people do it, but it does not work for me. Could anyone take a look and tell if they see a problem?

This is the part where i make the url into what I need it to be after a successfull submit:

```
if ($validator->success()) {
    (new ProductRepository)->addProduct($inputData);

    header('Location: addBook.php?success');
}
```

And here I would like a simple message "Product Added" to be displyed when this URL is met:

```
    <?php if (isset($_GET['addBook.php?success'])) {?>
    <div>
        <h3>
            <center>Product Added!</center>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
```

For some reason this doesn't work. and it shows no errors. Before data is submited, URL is: addBook.php, after I submit the data successfully, it's addProduct.php?success, so that works, but nothing else.

Comment: Try only $_GET['success']

Comment: `addBook.php` is the file, `success` is the query string variable that you would need to check against.

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan Thanks man, it worked!

Comment: Remember to self answer your question; If the suggestion above worked.

Comment: @AkinOkegbileHello, yes, thank you for reminder. I still cant do it for the next 18 hours tho. Will do it then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an asnwer from the guy in comments. I had to do: (isset($_GET['success'])) instead of (isset($_GET['addBook.php?success'])).